# create pagination for array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api, pagination

I have a nice list of 200 pokemons from pokeapi.co and I have tried to paginate them (20 item/page, 10 pages). I found a nice tutorial, made my own pagination based on that but at the end just doesnt works.

I have tried to call the nextPage, previousPage, firstPage and lastPage. fuctions via HTML button but I get the following error in all 4 cases:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: previousPage is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:21)

I am beginner and I dont see the whole picture as clean as a pro, I dont know lot of things and cant figure it out whats wrong with my code!

Please take a look at my code.

Thank you for your time!

```js
//wrapping pokemonList array in an IIFE
const pokemonRepository = (function() {
  const pokemonList = [];
  const apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=200';

  
  //Pagination
  var list = new Array();
  var pageList = new Array();
  var currentPage = 1;
  var itemPerPage = 20;
  var numberOfPages = 0;

  function makeList() {
    for (let x = 0; x < 200; x++)
      list.push(x);
    numberOfPages = getNumberOfPages();
  }

  function getNumberOfPages() {
    return Math.ceil(list.length / itemPerPage);
  }

  function nextPage() {
      currentPage += 1;
      loadTheList();
  }

  function previousPage() {
    currentPage -= 1;
    loadTheList();
  }

  function firstPage() {
    currentPage = 1;
    loadTheList();
  }

  function lastPage() {
    currentPage = numberOfPages;
    loadTheList();
  }

  function loadTheList() {
    var begin = ((currentPage - 1) * itemPerPage);
    var end = begin + itemPerPage;

    pageList = list.slice(begin, end);
    drawList(); //draws out our data
    check(); //determines the state of the pagination button
  }

  function drawList() {
    document.getElementById('pokemon-list').innerHTML = '';
    for (let r = 0; r < pageList.length; r++) {
      document.getElementById('pokemon-list').innerHTML += pageList[r] + '';
    }
  }

  function check() {
    document.getElementById("next").disabled = currentPage == numberOfPages ? true : false;
    document.getElementById("previous").disabled = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
    document.getElementById("first").disabled = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
    document.getElementById("last").disabled = currentPage == numberOfPages ? true : false;
  }

  function load() {
    makeList();
    loadTheList();
  }
  //pagination end

  return {
    ...
  };
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loading"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
  <h1 class="main-title">Pokédex</h1>
  <ul class="pokemon-list" id="pokemon-list">
  </ul>

<!-- buttons for pagination-->
  <button id="first" onClick="firstPage()">first</button>
  <button id="previous" onClick="previousPage()">previous</button>
  <button id="next" onClick="nextPage()">next</button>
  <button id="last" onClick="lastPage()">last</button>

  <script src="js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fetch-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A question should have a [mcve] and not just a code dump of the complete project/site.

Comment: The issue itself telling you that the html is unable to access `previousPage()` function. As I can see that its enclosed in an constant function so its scope is limited to that `pokemonRepository` function only

Comment: All your functions are only available inside that IIFE. By using the `onclick` attribute in the markup they have to be available in the global scope. Either move them into the global scope or, imho the better option, use `.addEventListener()` to assign them to the elements.

Comment: Also, it should be ```onclick``` instead of ```onClick``` in the html.

Comment: @ikhvjs I have noticed and corrected!  Thank you anyway

Comment: @Andreas I made with `.addEventListener()` just as you said but now when I click on whichever button my whole list disapper

Comment: Then start debugging.